# How could I fix the lowercase problem in nextgen gallery?

Tags: plugins, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am using nextgen gallery plugin with this code:

```
$galleries = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT t.*, tt.* 
FROM $wpdb->nggallery AS t 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->nggpictures AS tt ON t.gid = tt.galleryid 
WHERE tt.exclude != 1 
GROUP BY tt.galleryid ORDER by tt.galleryid");

echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$galleries[0]->gid.' template=galleryview images=0]'); 

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $galleries as $gallery ) {
    $img_date = explode("-", $gallery->imagedate);
    $ano = $img_date[0];
    $mes = $img_date[1];
    $img_gallery_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/'.$ano.'/'.$mes.'/'.$gallery->filename;
    // $gallery->filename trazendo lowercase
    echo 
        '<li>
            <img width="139px" height="83px" src="'.$img_gallery_url.'" alt="'.$gallery->alttext.'"/>
            <a href="#">'.$gallery->name.'</a>
        </li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But the `$gallery->filename` is coming lowercase.
My images are being saved without being mandatory to be lowercase.

- How could I fix this ?
- Is there a way to make mandatory lowercase in wordpress image upload
  (nextgen gallery)?
- Is there a way to make `$gallery->filename` bring the right
  filename, without making it lowercase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some pain, I found this at the [plugin documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/)

> For a single picture : [singlepic id=x w=width h=height
>   mode=web20|watermark float=left|right]

So my echo became this:

```
echo 
'<li>
    '.do_shortcode('[singlepic id='.$gallery->previewpic.' w=139 h=83 float=left]').'
    <a href="#">'.$gallery->title.'</a>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

### DataBase handling

> **ALWAYS** do a proper `prepare()` when receiving data from the DB.

I can't say it often enough…

```
$galleries = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT t.*, tt.* 
        FROM %s AS t 
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->nggpictures AS tt ON t.gid = tt.galleryid 
        WHERE tt.exclude != 1 
        GROUP BY tt.galleryid ORDER by tt.galleryid
    " ), 
    $wpdb->nggallery 
);
```

### NextGen…

…simply isn't involved. You're doing a normal request via the WP DB class object. So the problem is completely elsewhere. I'd suggest to turn off all plugins aside from NextGen, activate the default TwentyTen/Eleven Theme, drop your code in there and then see if it happens again.

#### Update: *If* the plugin is lowercasing the files…

In this case, the nextgen plugin is (90% chance that it's that way) `lowercase`ing the files on upload. Not much what you can do against it without killing the plugin itself (updates, core changes, etc.).

#### My suggestion:

1. Fix it when calling the files if you want a *prettier* output. `ucwords`, `mb_strtoupper()`, etc.
2. Don't fix it if it's only about the filename.

Comment: in wp_ngg_pictures (database table) the filename is all saved as lowercase, and the images in my folder are with normal text (uppercase, first uppercase the others lowercase ...). The idea for the theme and plugin didn't work. Any other ideas ?

Comment: see update ....

Comment: my problem is not the filename prettier. for example. my file (in the folder) is named "WinteR.jpg", I want to use this filename as a src from img exhibition. But the filename is always lowercase. So I want get the file name as it is in the folder OR save in the database the filename as it is in the folder. not lowering.